# Azure Active Directory User Not Active

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I have created Azure AD and create new users..

My default user is 'isanka88@gmail.com' and it's Microsoft account user.Also i have created User called 'Mangala@Bursa.onmicrosoft.com'  and it's Azure Active Directory user.

User Image here

[image]

But when I going to my MVC application using these user names, Microsoft account user logged successfully.But Azure Active Directory user did not login successfully.

I have no idea whether is it MVC application problem or Azure AD user account problem.

Anyone can help me to sort this out..

Comment: Could you share more details? What's the error message when login failed?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the error message when you login? Did you login as the below image:
[image]